If $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R^3})$, then $\frac{\hat{f}(\xi)\cdot \xi}{2\pi i |\xi|^2} \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R^3})$.
I have that $f$ is an $L^2(\mathbb{R^3})$ function, so I know that $\hat{f}$ its Fourier transform is in $L^2(\mathbb{R^3})$ too. I want to prove that:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\hat{f}(\xi)\cdot \xi}{2\pi i |\xi|^2} \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R^3}).
\end{equation}
The problem is when $0\in K\subset \mathbb{R^3}$, $K$ compact. Because,
\begin{equation}
    \int_K \frac{|\hat{f}(\xi)\cdot \xi|}{2\pi  |\xi|^2}d\xi\leq \frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_K \frac{|\hat{f}(\xi)| |\xi|}{|\xi|^2}d\xi=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_K \frac{|\hat{f}(\xi)|}{|\xi|}d\xi,
\end{equation}
where in the first inequality I used the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. So the term into the integral can explode close to zero. It will be great any suggestion for this problem.

Use Cauchy-Schwartz again, if $K$ is contained in a ball of radius $R$, then $\int_K |\zeta|^{-2} d\zeta \le \int_{S^2}\int_{0}^R r^{-2} r^2 dr dS < \infty$.

@Yimin thanks a lot, yes integration in polar coordinates is the key.
